# Resizing image to fit in MapView's leftCalloutAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm trying to resize a UIImage to fit inside a map view's annotation in the `leftCalloutAccessoryView` slot. I've attempted (poorly) to add constraints but the image is not showing up - without the constraints it shows up, but it's far too large. Now with them, it doesn't appear at all, I'm thinking because it's been resized out of the view. I tried adding a `leftAnchor` and `topAnchor` but got an error because I'm not entirely sure what I should be pinning it to - the accessory view? Annotation view? Anyway here's the code thus far:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let identifier = "Restaurants"

    if annotation is Restaurants {
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true

            let infoButton = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            let imgView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "TTT"))

            // constraints
            imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

            annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton
            annotationView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imgView
        } else {
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
        }
        return annotationView
    }
    return nil
}
```

Do I just need to be adding side and top anchors, or is there a different way of going about this entirely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the `UIImageView` size to the created `MKPinAnnotationView`

and then call aspect fit on it like this:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: annotationView!.frame.height, height: annotationView!.frame.height))

imageView.image = UIImage(named: "TTT")
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

annotationView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imageView
```